# mongoimport error - Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, import, mac-os-x, mongodb-3.0

I am currently trying to learn `MongoDB` and I am having trouble finding a solution for this problem. When I run a `mongoimport` command it I get the following error:

```
~ mongoimport --host localhost --port 27017 --db test --collection people --file ~/Downloads/mongodb-consultas.json --jsonArray
2015-09-27T20:46:03.228-0600    [........................] test.people  0.0 B/684.2 KB (0.0%)
2015-09-27T20:46:03.745-0600    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2015-09-27T20:46:03.745-0600    imported 0 documents
```

When I substituted `localhost` for `127.0.0.1` I get the following error:

```
~  mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --db test --collection people --file ~/Downloads/mongodb-consultas.json --jsonArray
2015-09-28T15:15:42.047-0600    connected to: 127.0.0.1:27017
2015-09-28T15:15:42.049-0600    Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
2015-09-28T15:15:42.049-0600    imported 0 documents
```

The document that I am trying to import is not corrupted as I got it from a MongoDB tutorial, and it is working for other users.

My MongoDB shell version is 3.0.6.

I have a `MongoDB` server by running `mongod` in the command line. The command `mongo` runs fine as well.

My firewall allows incoming connections for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the error and checked out, the problem is resist with mongoimport syntax. The mongoimport shell is unable to find the location of (`.json`) file.

And also there is mistake like [--jsonArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-jsonarray).

As per `MongoDB BOL` **--jsonArray** Modifies the output of `mongoexport` to write the entire contents of the export as a single `JSON` array. By default `mongoexport` writes data using one `JSON` document for every `MongoDB` document.

> ***Note:-*** Accepts the `import` of data expressed with multiple `MongoDB` documents within a single `JSON` array. Limited to imports
>   of **16 MB** or smaller.

For Simple mongoimport syntax will be like that

```
mongoimport -d databasename -c collectionname (File Location of json file.json)
```

**For Example**

```
mongoimport -d test -c zips C:\MongoDBDBA\zips.json

2018-02-07T08:32:31.084+0300    connected to: localhost
2018-02-07T08:32:31.532+0300    imported 29353 documents
```

IN the above `mongoimport` syntax the database name is `test` and collection name is `zips` and `C:\MongoDBDBA\zips.json` is the (`.json`) file location.

**For Example with localhost and port number 27017**

If you want to use `localhost` and by default `port` number `27017` in `mongoimport` then simply the syntax will be like that

```
mongoimport --host localhost --port 27017 -d blog -c posts C:\MongoDBDBA\posts.json

2018-02-07T10:48:54.340+0300    connected to: localhost:27017
2018-02-07T10:48:56.333+0300    [########################] blog.posts   33.9MB/33.9MB (100.0%)
2018-02-07T10:48:56.345+0300    [########################] blog.posts   33.9MB/33.9MB (100.0%)
2018-02-07T10:48:56.346+0300    imported 1000 documents
```

Here in the above syntax `blog` is the database name and collection name is `posts`.

> **Most Important Note:-** Run `mongoimport` from the **system command line**, not the `mongo shell`.

For your further ref [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Answer (score 1):

Check if localhost is getting telnet from command prompt.

```
$ telnet localhost 27017
```

If it is not getting connected then check `/etc/hosts` on your machine.

It should have uncommented entry as  `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER : Very Rookie MongoDBA**

My guess would be the Document Size

According to ["MongoDB Limits and Thresholds"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

> BSON Document Size
>
> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.
>
> The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API. See mongofiles and the documentation for your driver for more information about GridFS.

It may have timed out looking for the end of the Document.

You should [bsondump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/bsondump/) the file to a json file and check the contents for BUT DO NOT IMPORT THE RESULTING JSON because some fidelity is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show that JSON file .As per error "found no opening bracket '['" mongoimport not able to find opening bracket. So enclose whole JSON in [...]
then try hopefully will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate the json documents which are being imported into MongoDB collection using **mongoimport**

According to the above mentioned error description it seems that json file is invalid due to which mongoimport tool fails to import documents into mongo collection